# Render sibling element only if checkbox checked in ractive js

Tags: jquery, ractivejs

I want to toggle sibling element only if checkbox is checked

I am using *ractive.js* and below you can see my template

I am also using *icheck Jquery plugin* for checkbox, so that I can't bind ractive function on input element.

```
{{#each services}}
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ selectedServices }}" value="{{Id}}" class="minimal flat-green"/>
            <span>{{Title}}</span>
        </label>
        {{#if IsMultiple && isShow}}
        <label>
            <input class="timeRange" type="text" name="range_5" value="">
        </label>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

I really don't know how to toggle `isShow` if its sibling checkbox is checked.
Please help me.

Comment: Could you also add your data object here too? You can bind to the checkbox, and show based on that - but may need to alter how your data is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please supply a jsbin or JSFiddle as an example? It would make it a little easier to answer the question.

I'm assuming you can't do this:
http://jsbin.com/cevivi/1/edit?html,js,output
Which checks to see if the current ID is in the selectedServices array.

This should do it, although without an example from you I can't be certain:
http://jsbin.com/cevivi/2/edit?html,js,output

We wait for the value of the checkbox to change, then update the array accordingly through the built-in event handling.

The check to show/hide the input box, is just whether or not the Id is in the array.

Hope that helps.